# Convert form results to array with jQuery or other

Tags: jquery, forms, jsp, web

I'm trying to get a form result to an array so it can be handled by the next JSP page.

Currently I have this code:

```
$("seguimiento").submit(function(){
        var labels = new Array();
        var val = new Array();
        $(":input").each(function(){
           if ($(this).val() >0) {
              labels.push($(this).attr('name'));
              val.push($(this).val());
           }
        });
        console.log("ya hemos rellenado los arrays");
       $.post("enviar.jsp", {"etiquetas": labels.join(','), "valores": val.join(',')});
     });
```

But it is just not working at all, I don't even get on the console the debugging message.

Of course my form has `name="seguimiento"`

Comment: instead of .name() use .attr('name');

Comment: one more , instead of this use $(this)

Comment: @Bhadra updated the code with what you suggested, but I'm being redirected to my same page, not to enviar.jsp

Comment: Now ,are you getting console log message?

Comment: Nope, not that either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) or [serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

```
$.post("enviar.jsp",$("form").serialize(),function(d){});
```

To get the console msg

```
$("form[name='seguimiento']").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var values = $(this).serializeArray();//this contains the array you want
        console.log(values);
        $.post('enviar.jsp',values,function(d){
             //d is the output of enviar.jsp
             console.log(d);
        });
     });
```

Depending on the data, you can consider using `window.location` to redirect to enviar.jsp and send the data as url variables.

Comment: tried like this `$("seguimiento").submit(function(){
            $.post("enviar.jsp",$("form").serialize());
         });` but it is not working, I get redirected to the same page and not to `enviar.jsp`

Comment: `$.post` is an Ajax implementation by jquery, that is, it sends the info behind the scenes without actually redirecting the browser. If you need to actually redirect/open enviar.jsp, then why not use `<form action="enviar.jsp" ...`, and actually submit the form?

Comment: Because then all the operation of getting the form into the array and getting rid of the empty values will be done on the server. The main intention was to avoid the server from doing that operation to release some CPU

Comment: It works now with what you say but as you also stated it is not redirecting me, because it's Ajax.
My fault misreading the .post() function in the jquery API, thanks anyway for the help!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can not pass arrays of javascript, Instead of sending array pass comma separated strings, you can use join to make comma separated string from array.

*Change*

```
$.post("enviar.jsp", {etiquetas: labels, valores: val});
```

*To*

```
$.post("enviar.jsp", {"etiquetas": labels.join(','), "valores": val.join(',')});
```

Comment: tried that, but not working, it doesn't redirect me to the enviar.jsp web, but instead reloads the page I'm in.

Comment: Are you able to redirect with passing data?